# Open a PDF from Excel with VBA in Google Chrome on a specific page

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, pdf

I am creating a macro in Excel that should open a PDF document on a specified page with chrome.

Generally, the opening part works. My problem is that when I add the page number (e.g. #page=15) to the url, the shell encodes the "#" symbol into "%23", which Chrome is not able to interpret correctly (file not found).

Here is my code

```
'The path to the file, replaces spaces with the encoding "%20"
Path = Replace((filePath& "#Page=" & iPageNum), " ", "%20")

Dim wshShell, chromePath As String, shellPath As String
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
chromePath = wshShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe\")

shellPath = CStr(chromePath) & " -url " & Path

If Not chromePath = "" Then
    'how I first tried it:
    Shell (shellPath) 

    'for testing purposes, led to the same result though:
    Shell ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" ""C:\Users\t.weinmuellner\Desktop\Evon\PDF Opening\PDFDocument.pdf#page=17""") 

End If
```

Is there a different way to do this with Chrome? I haven't found anything that reads the installation path dynamically.

Comment: Is it also possible to use Adobe Acrobat Reader instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify the protocol `file:///` if you want to load files from the local hard disk. Then `#` gets not translated into `%23`.

```
 Shell ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" ""file:///C:\Users\t.weinmuellner\Desktop\Evon\PDF Opening\PDFDocument.pdf#page=17""")
```

Comment: Thank you! Such an easy fix and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

If Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed on the system I would suggest to use the funcion `openPDF` from Daniel Pineault. This will open the file in Adobe Reader directly. You can find the source code of the function [here](https://www.devhut.net/2013/12/04/VBA-open-a-pdf-to-a-specific-page/)

A test could look like that

```
Sub TestSO()

Dim fileName As String
Dim pageNo As Long

    fileName = "Path and filename of PDF"
    pageNo = 20
    OpenPDF fileName, 20

End Sub
```

Comment: *"If Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed on the system what I assume because it has to be otherwise a solution with Chrome would also fail"* Why would it fail? Chrome has a built in PDF viewer and doesn't use Acrobat Reader at all in default mode.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not know that Chrome has a built in PDF viewer. I was just assuming it uses Adobe for it. I will correct my posting.

Comment: Useful in any case :-) @Storax